# Change scene before rendering ShaderPass

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I have a scene and I have a shader that apply green colored square on top of the scene. I have a white sphere but I want that sphere to be invisible when it falls outside of the green square. Can I remove the sphere before the render pass and re-add before green color shader pass? If not, how can I achieve what I want?

Here're my render passes:

```
renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);

colorifyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ColorifyShader);
colorifyPass.uniforms[ "color" ].value = new THREE.Color(0x00ff00);
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(renderPass);
composer.addPass(colorifyPass);
composer.addPass(copyPass);
copyPass.renderToScreen = true;
```

Here is the screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like `THREE.MaskPass` is what you want. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_advanced.html. You will have to study the source code carefully.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it with MaskPass but thanks to your example I did it using double composer as shown in my posted answer. If you have a better suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WestLangley's example I ended up achieving what I want this way:

```
function initShaders() {
    renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);

    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    composer.addPass(renderPass);
    composer.addPass(copyPass);
    copyPass.renderToScreen = true;

    colorifyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ColorifyShader);
    colorifyPass.uniforms[ "color" ].value = new THREE.Color(0x00ff00);
    composerIR = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    composerIR.addPass(renderPass);
    composerIR.addPass(colorifyPass);
    composerIR.addPass(copyPass);
    copyPass.renderToScreen = true;
}
```

And added this code to render() function:

```
    renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    camera.fov = 45;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    hotSpotsRoot.visible = false;

    renderer.clear();
    composer.render(delta);

    if (irMode) {
        var irWidth = 450;
        renderer.setViewport(width / 2 - irWidth / 2 + 10, 200, irWidth, irWidth);
        camera.fov = 25;
        camera.aspect = 1;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        hotSpotsRoot.visible = true;

        composerIR.render(delta);
    }
```